# Removing passwords from excel files in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, excel-interop

I have been using the code supplied by @inwenis via http://pastebin.com/UCqXUYHU

it seems to work and will remove one or 2 passwords for files in the folder but will either fail after 2 solved excel sheets or if the password is more that 30 rows down in the password list.
can anyone point me to where the error may be in automating it for more than 2 sheets or a larger password list.

```
      param(
        $encrypted_path = "C:\PoShTest\Encrypted\",
        $decrypted_Path = "C:\PoShTest\Decrypted\",
        $processed_Path = "C:\PoShTest\Processed\",
        $password_Path  = "C:\PoShTest\Passwords\Passwords.txt"
    )
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

    # Get Current EXCEL Process ID's so they are not affected by the scripts cleanup
    $currentExcelProcessIDs = (Get-Proces s excel).Id
    $startTime = Get-Date

    Clear-Host

    $passwords = Get-Content -Path $password_Path
    $encryptedFiles = Get-ChildItem $encrypted_path
    [int] $count = $encryptedFiles.count - 1
    $ExcelObj = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
    $ExcelObj.Visible = $false
    $encryptedFiles | % {
        $encryptedFile  = $_
        Write-Host "Processing" $encryptedFile.name -ForegroundColor "DarkYellow"
        Write-Host "Items remaining: " $count
        if ($encryptedFile.Extension -like "*.xls*") {
            $passwords | % {
                $password = $_
                # Attempt to open encryptedFile
                $Workbook = $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Open($encryptedFile.fullname, 1, $false,5, $password)
                $Workbook.Activate()

                # if password is correct save decrypted encryptedFile to $decrypted_Path
                if ($Workbook.Worksheets.count -ne 0 ) {
                    $Workbook.Password = $null
                    $savePath = Join-Path $decrypted_Path $encryptedFile.Name
                    Write-Host "Decrypted: " $encryptedFile.Name -f "DarkGreen"
                    $Workbook.SaveAs($savePath)
                    # Added to keep Excel process memory utilization in check
                    $ExcelObj.Workbooks.close()
                    # Move original encryptedFile to $processed_Path
                    Move-Item $encryptedFile.fullname -Destination $processed_Path -Force
                }
                else {
                    $ExcelObj.Workbooks.Close()
                }
            }
        }
    $count--
    }
    # Close Document and Application
    $ExcelObj.Workbooks.close()
    $ExcelObj.Application.Quit()

    $endTime = Get-Date

    Write-Host "Processing Complete!" -f "Green"
    Write-Host "Time Started   : " $startTime.ToShortTimeString()
    Write-Host "Time Completed : " $endTime.ToShortTimeString()
    Write-Host "Total Duration : " 
    $startTime - $endTime

# Remove any stale Excel processes created by this scripts execution
Get-Process excel `
| Where { $currentExcelProcessIDs -notcontains $_.id } `
| Stop-Process
```

Comment: *"point me to where the error may be"*  What error?  You don't say what is going wrong.

Comment: when run on a folder containing 10+ passworded excel sheets it will solve 2 and then fail to process the rest of them

Comment: Does it fail silently or is there any error/output?  Anything particular about the ones that work/fail?  Is it any old Excel file or just certain ones?  You're really asking the community to troubleshoot a script you didn't write without seeming to do any troubleshooting/testing yourself or even describing the repro steps clearly.

Comment: It appears to be doing what it's supposed to but isn't processing anything when it fails and continues to run through counting the files in the folder.
I have tried moving correct passwords to the top of the password list and this works for the 1st couple of files and then it appears to time out

Comment: all files in the folder are in the same files type - the only errors I can see when not running it silently are for the failed password attempts in the loop nothing weird.

Comment: Using the Office interops may be too problematic. Ultimately the files are csv (even after unzipping the .docx) and that may be an alternate route to processing w/o the Excel interops. Can you create a test excel file and see where it fails. Is it failing exactly at 30 lines or because of what line 30 has in it?

Comment: $Workbook may be $null when opening fails, you should check this bevor Activate().